# Why does libSDL_draw.[so/a] is not find when I lauch make?

Tags: c, makefile, sdl

I'm trying to compile a C code which need SDL libraries(v1.2), SDL_draw and a library imposed by my teacher. the .c and makefile code works on an other computer.
 I use a makefile and when I 'make' I get severals errors : 
- first SDL_draw cannot be find although I paste it in /usr/include/2011/lib/libSDL_draw.a
- all other libraire are 'skipping incompatible' (I hope that those are just warnings)
- I though that it was compiled in static and the .so wouldn't be needed.

And I wondered what is the mysterious variable LFLMAC.

/**outup given by terminal**/

```
gcc -o demo1 demo1.o  -g -L/usr/include/2011/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lSDLmain -lSDL -lSDL_ttf -lSDL_image -lSDL_draw -lSDL_phelma
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/include/2011/lib/libSDLmain.a when searching for -lSDLmain
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/include/2011/lib/libSDL.so when searching for -lSDL
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/include/2011/lib/libSDL.a when searching for -lSDL
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/include/2011/lib/libSDL_ttf.so when searching for -lSDL_ttf
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/include/2011/lib/libSDL_ttf.a when searching for -lSDL_ttf
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/include/2011/lib/libSDL_image.so when searching for -lSDL_image
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/include/2011/lib/libSDL_image.a when searching for -lSDL_image
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/include/2011/lib/libSDL_draw.so when searching for -lSDL_draw
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/include/2011/lib/libSDL_draw.a when searching for -lSDL_draw
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL_draw
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [demo1] Erreur 1
```

/**makefile**/

`

```
DIRSDL=/usr/include/2011

CFLAGS=-g -O2 -I$(DIRSDL)/include 
LDFLAGS=$(LFLMAC) -g -L$(DIRSDL)/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lSDLmain -lSDL -lSDL_ttf -lSDL_image -lSDL_draw -lSDL_phelma

demo1: demo1.o 
    gcc -o demo1 demo1.o $(LDFLAGS)

demo1.o : demo1.c
    gcc -c $(CFLAGS)  demo1.c
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`skipping incompatible` linker message means that the library is incompatible with the binary currently being linked. E.g. you are linking a 64-bit binary with 32-bit libraries, or vice versa.

Try invoking:

```
file demo1.o 
file /usr/include/2011/lib/libSDLmain.a
```

from the shell to see what architectures these files are for.

Comment: demo1.o: ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped  \n  readelf -h libSDLmain.a | grep 'Class\|File\|Machine'
File: libSDLmain.a(SDL_dummy_main.o)
  Class:                             ELF64
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
 Indeed my ubuntu 11.04 is in 32 bit

Comment: @WilliamBoshi It looks like demo1.o is a 32-bit object but libSDLmain.a is a 64-bit object library. They are incompatible, both need to be either 32- or 64-bit.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try to reinstall a 64 bit ubuntu because I didn't manage to compile libSDL_draw in 32 bits